# Image alternate text overflow issue and accessibility

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I've been working on improving accessibility on a site and for that, I started adding alternate text to images. Since all images were available, alt text never showed up so I intentionally added a broken URL and this is what I am seeing

[image: Alternate text overflowing on the header]

The alternate text is going over the heading and even overflowing on the right side. Now, I know properties like **overflow: hidden** and **word-break: break-all** would restrict the text within the 25px square space I have allocated for the image but I am not sure about any other resulting complications that could come as a consequence. The image is really a small one (25px x 25px) and the alternate text varies from 15 to 30 characters. So, what's a good way to fix this without compromising on any of screen readers' functionality or on any other accessibility considerations?

Comment: The answer to this really depends on the situation of the images and what they are used for. Are they part of a focusable element? Do they have a related element that they compliment? etc. etc. Could you provide a fiddle as there are numerous techniques you could use but they are all influenced by the use case.

Comment: Hey Graham, thanks for your comment! Here's a fiddle for a situation similar to this one https://jsfiddle.net/myeo8w0g/7/. This is a logo for a college and it's right next to the college title and both of them are inside a link that goes to the college's official site.

Answer (score 1):

If your image size is going to be small every where then you can do like this.

```
img[alt].no-alt-show {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

and just add class no-alt-show in your HTML.

By doing this you can hide alt text or you can set font size as per requirement.

Comment: Not a good idea I am afraid. Custom style sheets (that many disabled users will use) will just override this back to a readable font size. It also means managing a load of classes on the page, which leads to mistakes. What happens if I have two images that are too small on mobile but one is large enough on desktop to contain its alt text? Will Google penalise you for hiding text in a way that used to be blackhat SEO for keyword stuffing? Also how is this any better than `overflow: hidden`, that solves the same issue without any of the drawbacks if we are going down the "hide alt text" route.